# TFTP Демон

Tags: windows, tftp, udp, c++, linux

Дедушка Мороз, это не просьба, а реальное предложение заработать...

В одном из обсуждений я пообещал написать TFTP, пока что только сервер. Не знаю, как выкладывание решений вписывается в рамки данного сайта, но давайте попробуем узнать, что из этого выйдет.

Моя страничка с описанием: http://mikelsv.livejournal.com/7984.html , SVN svn://svn.loglist.org:2402/usr/svn/opensource/msv-tftpd и код для тех кому лень лезть на svn http://pastebin.com/5xgJGgpJ . Последний сохранить в msv-tftpd.cpp и g++ ./msv-tftpd.cpp . Тестировать линуксовым tftp.

Просьба не бить за весь код в одном файле. Мне так проще разрабатывать. Если сделать по стандарту, тут будет двадцать файлов, заголовки в h, код в cpp. И разработка банально встанет.

Читать код стоит с низу с функции main(), постепенно залезая выше. Попытка читать сверху взорвет мозг в следствии нарушения логической связи.

Помню были вопросы. Сервер пока только на UDP, насчет TCP надо подумать. Для API не вижу смысла и потребности. Кто-то сказал, что в линуксе и винде разный формат текстовых файлов. Вообще они одинаковые, \r\n не считается. Проблема с переходом на линукс в том, что нужно учесть некоторые особенности и подключить нужные библиотеки. Совет писать на чистом си, ну это неправильно, терять всю мощь с++.

Собственно вот так. Давайте вопросы в ваших ответах :)

Comment: В чем суть предложения? $$$ за перенос проги под линух?

Comment: Если честно, я думал будет интересно людям. Вижу просчитался с популярностью проекта. Когда сказал, что хочу написать TFTP было много вопросов и предложений.

Суть - продолжить интересное обсуждение. Может прикрутить API или приделать TCP. Значит допишу до логического завершения и положу на полку.

А под линуксом оно работает. И под андроид перенесу, потренируюсь в добавлении программ на маркет.

Comment: @mikelsv, пока не работает (в линуксе). Но, за порыв плюсую.

Собралось с wrnings. Для запуска не от рута порт пришлось подправить (на 1169). **Хэлпа ( ./out --help) нет (это плохо)**.

Файл не передался (в конце (до 512 байт) грязь).

Пока дальше бэта-тестером быть не хочу.

Comment: У меня работает. Какой у вас линукс?

Это традиция собираться с варнингами, их три и они не влияют на работоспособность. Да, этот порт доступен только от рута.

Разработка в процессе. Анализ параметров и вывод справки будет в следующих версиях, как и чтение настроек из файла. В svn лежит новая версия с логами,расширенными настройками и поддержкой записи файла на сервер.

У меня все тесты прошли отлично, проверял tftp: connect ip, get msv-tftpd.cpp. И на других файлах тоже не видно проблем. На двух линуксах дебиане и федоре. Какой программой вы проверяли и с какими настройками,какой компилятор

Comment: "Это традиция собираться с варнингами". Да уж. Страшноватая традиция.

Comment: Страшноватая это с errorами. У меня библиотека с часто используемыми функциями выдает под сотню варнингов. Я давно забросил их исправление. На работоспособность это не влияет. Вот начал писать с нуля, посмотрим, долго ли продержусь. На линуксовые: нет пустой строки в конце файла я забиваю больше чем полностью.

Comment: @mikelsv, у меня ubuntu

    avp@avp-ubu1:/tmp$ uname -a
    Linux avp-ubu1 2.6.32-45-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 16 16:26:56 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    avp@avp-ubu1:/tmp$ cat /etc/issue
    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS \n \l
    avp@avp-ubu1:/tmp$ g++ --version
    g++.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

Какой программой проверял? С этим сложнее. tftp взял (не помню какую, а она сама не говорит...)
вызвал 

    sudo apt-get install tftp

потом (из /tmp) tftp, в ней 

    connect localhost 1169
    put pri.c

размером 277 байт. Создался файл размером 512 байт (первые 277 ОК).

Comment: Попробовал еще. Файлы длиннее 512 байт передает нормально. Но дальше начинаются фокусы...

    get ../t.c

ругается на хакера

    get ../zxzxz

говорит нет файла (правильно, но на хакера не ругается)

    get /tmp/xxx

такого файла нет, а передает 512 байт, начинающиеся словами

    Access violation

а потом текст от последнего переданного файла.

@mikelsv, тщательней надо отлаживаться, на бэту пока даже get не тянет.

Comment: @avp

    apt-cache show tftp

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо.

    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ apt-cache show tftp
    Package: tftp
    Priority: optional
    Section: universe/net
    Installed-Size: 88
    Maintainer: Ubuntu MOTU Developers <ubuntu-motu@lists.ubuntu.com>
    Original-Maintainer: Alberto Gonzalez Iniesta <agi@inittab.org>
    Architecture: amd64
    Source: netkit-tftp
    Version: 0.17-17ubuntu1
    Replaces: netstd
    ...

Вот что мне не понравилось - это `Replaces: netstd`. 

Я посмотрел

    The netstd package provides you with the standard networking services 

и ftp, telnet ... тоже заменены.

Это нормально?

Comment: @avp Вероятно да. По крайней мере у меня apt-cache этого netstd не нашёл. Возможно что-то древнее. Тем более, что этих сетевых программ по полдюжине на каждую функцию, а то и больше...

Comment: @avp,
Не досмотрел. В первой передаче файла всегда передается 512 байт. С хакером и отсутствием файла - именно так и написано в коде. Сделаю проверку на хакера первым.

Повторить get /tmp/xxx и получить Access violation не удается. За-то удалось скачать /etc/passwd. Да, тестировать надо тщательнее.

Answer (score 1):

[@mikelsv](/users/2575/mikelsv), у меня комментарии кончились.

Вы бы более-менее подробное описание своей программы где-нибудь (в легкодоступном месте и текстовом виде) выложили (что она должна и чего не должна делать). И протокол доступа к ней (в том числе формат UDP пакетов) и реакцию на ошибочные пакеты.

Или Вы считаете, что найдется много желающих тестировать ее, изучая исходник без нормальных комментариев? Надеюсь, Вы понимаете, что изучать (и даже читать) RFC тоже лениво.

Все таки, Ваша цель это еще один TFTP сервер, реализующий rfc (с Вашими дополнениями о хакерах)? Или собираетесь добавить новый функционал (например просмотр оглавления, получение stat() для файла)? Что Вы думаете о разных кодировках русского (имена файлов) в разных системах?

Возможно стоит сначала решить (обсудить) подобные вопросы, а уже потом писать код.